# logout without being at login shell

Tags: ubuntu, bash, ubuntu-server

In Ubuntu Desktop, there's a [command](http://dev.man-online.org/man1/gnome-session-quit/) to logout immediately, and the user can execute it without being at the login shell:

```
 $ gnome-session-quit --logout --no-prompt
```

**Q.** What is the equivalent command in Ubuntu Server, if any?

(I'm aware that `logout` at a non-login shell is [not allowed](https://superuser.com/questions/162653/logout-bash-logout-not-login-shell-use-exit), but perhaps there's a different command. The preferred solution logs out gracefully instead of e.g., killing daemons.)

Comment: When you say logout, do you mean you want to terminate the shell invoked at login, plus any child processes of that shell, regardless of the process you happen to be in at the moment?  So for example, if you were five bash shells down you want to issue a logout that will terminate the login shell, and as a result kill all the child shells and any processes they may have spawned?

Comment: Note that your statement that `exit` doesn't work in a non-login shell is incorrect, it is `logout` that doesn't work.  It isn't forbidden, it just doesn't make sense to logout if you aren't in a login shell.

Comment: @Paul, Ah, my mistake...thanks. Yes, I do mean terminate login shell plus its children. I fixed the question. If the user isn't allowed to use the `logout` command (regardless of whether it makes sense), wouldn't the command be considered "forbidden"?

Comment: Well I would say that "forbidden" is something you don't rights or permission to do.  Rather than something that doesn't make sense to do.  Like the difference between being not permitted to issue a command to shutdown a webserver (forbidden), versus trying to issue the same command where no webserver is running (no sense :))

Comment: @Paul, Ok, I'm with you now. :)

Comment: You could control-z (suspend) until you get to the login shell, then logout.  There may be better ways to do it however, so I'll wait and see what others come up with.

Comment: Just kill the login shell. Identifying the PID is the only issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pkill` or `skill` seem to be the answer:

```
$ bash
$ bash
$ pkill -KILL -u $USER

Ubuntu 11.10 mach1 tty1

mach1 login: _
```

From the `skill` [manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/dapper/man1/skill.1.html), other exit-signals can be used instead of `-KILL`:

```
   Name     Num   Action    Description

   ALRM      14   exit
   HUP        1   exit
   INT        2   exit
   KILL       9   exit      this signal may not be blocked
   PIPE      13   exit
   POLL           exit
   PROF           exit
   TERM      15   exit
   USR1           exit

   USR2           exit
   VTALRM         exit
   STKFLT         exit      may not be implemented
```